# Androidで標準以外のフォントを使用する

Tags: java, android

Android 端末向けに OpenGL を使った簡単なゲームを作ろうと思っており、その中で独自のフォントを使いたいです。

作るアプリでは以下を使っています。

- AppCompatActivity
- GLSurfaceView
- Renderer

また、描画のためには以下を使っています。この3つは、GLSurfaceView配下です。

- Bitmap
- Canvas
- Paint

フォントを使うために `paint.setTypeface( Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ipag.ttf") );` を使いたいのですが、getAssets 解決ができません。
これを解決する方法がわかりません。

どなたか解決方法を教えていただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

#### ソースコード

- MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.ma2.opengles;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it
        // as the ContentView for this Activity
        mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(mGLView);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGLView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGLView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);  //this line is api 19+
            } else {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

- MyGLSurfaceView.java

```
package com.example.ma2.opengles;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    GLRenderer myRenderer;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        myRenderer = new GLRenderer();
        setRenderer(myRenderer);
    }

}
```

- GLRenderer.java

```
package com.example.ma2.opengles;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.FontMetrics;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

public class GLRenderer implements Renderer {

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap bmp;

        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        {
            // Canvasを使って、文字をBitMap化
            bmp = createStrImage( "123" );
        }

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        int[] buffers = new int[1];
        gl.glGenTextures(1, buffers, 0);
        int textureName = buffers[0];
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL10.GL_NEAREST);

        bmp.recycle();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.50f, 0.50f, 1.0f);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        float uv[] = {
                0.0f, 0.0f,// 左上
                0.0f, 1.0f,// 左下
                1.0f, 0.0f,// 右上
                1.0f, 1.0f,// 右下
        };

        ByteBuffer bbuv = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(uv.length * 4);
        bbuv.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        FloatBuffer fbuv = bbuv.asFloatBuffer();
        fbuv.put(uv);
        fbuv.position(0);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, fbuv);
        float positions[] = {
                // ! x y z
                -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // 左上（uv一行目に対応）
                -1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f, // 左下（uv二行目に対応）
                1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // 右上（uv三行目に対応）
                1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f, // 右下（uv四行目に対応）
        };

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(positions.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer fb = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        fb.put(positions);
        fb.position(0);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, fb);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    }

    public Bitmap createStrImage( String str ) {
        Paint paint = new Paint( Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG );
        paint.setTypeface( Typeface.DEFAULT );
        paint.setTypeface( Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ipag.ttf") );
        paint.setTextSize( 30 );

        Paint.FontMetrics fm = paint.getFontMetrics();
        paint.setARGB( 255, 255, 255, 0 );

        float width = paint.measureText( str );
        float height = -fm.top + fm.bottom;

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( (int)width, (int)height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas( bitmap );
        canvas.drawText( str, 0, -fm.top, paint );

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: createFromFile()でファイルから読み込めるはずなんですが、ご検討されましたか。

Answer (score 0):

getAssets()は、実際にはActivity.getAssets()等の呼び出しであるため、createStrImageの引数でActivity等の参照を渡す必要があると思われます。

Comment: 返答してくれた皆さんありがとうございます。

まず、createStrImage を MainActivityクラスのメンバーに変更しました。
使うのは GLRendererクラスのonSurfaceChanged内です。
・・・クラスを跨いだら、
- MainActivityクラス: getAssetsを使うなら使っている関数(今回の場合:createFromAsset)をstaticにしてくださいと言われ
- GLRendererクラス  : こちらでは非staticに・・・と言われるようになりました

paint.setTypeface の一行がネックになっているので、getAssetsを引数にすればと考えています。
作業はこれからですが回答をあったので現状まで。